# Does Pathfinder allow divine casters to use shields as divine foci?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, holy-symbol

Inspired by [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/56403/somatic-spell-component-with-shield), I was wondering if Pathfinder RAW allows a holy symbol to take the form of a shield (some other D&D editions have a similar rule), or does it have to take a more traditional form, such as an amulet?

P.S. The [Paizo thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2m5fh?Can-your-shield-be-your-holy-symbol) on this topic says that it ought to be in the core rulebooks, but isn't; instead, several splatbook suggestions are pointed out there...

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

> **Create Reliquary Arms and Shields**
>
> Your magical creations are infused with divine power.
>
> **Prerequisites:** Craft Magic Arms and Armor, ability to cast consecrate or desecrate.
>
> **Benefit:** When you craft a magic weapon, magic armor, or magic shield, you may add one casting of consecrate or desecrate as part of the item crafting process. This increases the item’s price by 250 gp.
>
> The item becomes a reliquary and can be used as a holy (or unholy) symbol divine focus of your deity. If you cast consecrate or desecrate, your reliquary counts as a permanent fixture for that spell while it remains in the spell’s area.

Source: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/create-reliquary-arms-and-shields